# Запуск метода onNavigationItemSelected

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-navigation-drawer

Добрый день.
В `MainActivity` реализован метод

```
    //* выбор кнопки в меню сэндвича
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.menu_main) {
        //* появление фрагмента Главная            
    }
    else

    if (id == R.id.menu_news) {
        //* появление фрагмента НОВОСТИ
    }
    else

    if (id == R.id.menu_video) {
        //* появление фрагмента ВИДЕО
    }
```

и т.д. пунктов там много. Вопрос вот в чем...

Во фрагменте ГЛАВНАЯ часть этих пунктов повторяется. Ну т.е. тоже есть кнопки Новости, Видео и т.п.

При нажатии на эти пункты из сенвича - открываются соответствующие фрагменты. А при нажатии на эти же пункты из фрагмента ГЛАВНАЯ, тоже открываются эти же соответствующие фрагменты (новости, видео и т.п). Но надо как-то указать это и в сендвиче, что мол юзер уже на данной странице.

Если я делаю вызов этих фрагментов(новости, главная) из меню сендвича то все - ок, для юзера устанавливается в самом сендвиче маячок (цвет меню меняется), но это маячок понятное дело не устанавливается если я тыкаю по тем же пунктам (новости, видео и т.п.) с фрагмента ГЛАВНАЯ.

Есть мысль, что я должен запускать на каждой кнопке фрагмента ГЛАВНАЯ что-то типа такого но что передавать там - ????????

```
    if (getActivity() != null)
                activityMain = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            activityMain.onNavigationItemSelected(?????????)
```

если это верное решение конечно. Или подскажите какое-то другое. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве аргумента метода `onNavigationItemSelected` идёт `MenuItem` его вы можете получить по `ID` из `Menu`, кое находится в `NavigationView`:

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.about)
```

Comment: navigationView = (NavigationView) view.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

activityMain.onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_market));

я наверное где-то что-то упустил. но после этих манипуляций мне ошибку выдает с нулем

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Menu android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.getMenu()' on a null object reference

Comment: Туплю. activityMain.onNavigationItemSelected(activityMain.navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_other));

так все работает. НО маячок в сендвиче не активен. Т.е. если в сендвиче выбрал главную, этот пункт окрасился и юзер понял что на главной. 

Если потом из фрагмента ГЛАВНАЯ ушел на какой-то пункт, то все работает, но окрашеный пунктв сендвиче так и остаеться на Главной.  Весь сыр-бор именно из-за этого маячка.

Я то подумал , если запускать метод onNavigationItemSelected() из фрагмента с нужными параметрами, пункт меню сендвича будет окрашеваться и показывать где я нахожусь. но нет.

Comment: @Andrey, ну... попробуйте вызвать ещё `NavigationView.setCheckedItem (int id)`